# meteor updated, server restarting over and over again

Tags: node.js, meteor

I just updated to meteor 6.5 with

```
meteor update
```

I also updated the packages with

```
mrt update
```

and now when I start my server with

```
mrt -p 3001
```

I get:

> Meteor server restarted (1x)

And the 1x keep increasing. To stop it I need to kill the process with:

```
$ top // find the process id of node
$ kill -9 147854 // 147854 is the process id of node
```

I can't make the server run normally, any solution?

Edit: When running with meteor --release 0.6.4.1

> No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
>   => Errors prevented startup: Exception while bundling application: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   '/home/test/.meteor/packages/standard-app-packages/package.js'
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:338:18)
>       at Object.fs.openSync (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/lib/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:68:26)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:182:15)
>       at _.extend.initFromPackageDir (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/packages.js:163:19)
>       at *.extend.initFromWarehouse (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/packages.js:197:10)
>       at Object.*.extend.get (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/packages.js:353:15)
>       at self.api.use (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/bundler.js:111:28)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:78:11)
>       at Object.self.api.use (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/bundler.js:110:9)
>       at _.extend.init_from_app_dir [as on_use_handler] (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/packages.js:238:11)
>       at _.extend.use (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/bundler.js:464:11)
>       at Object.exports.bundle (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/bundler.js:873:12)
>       at /home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/run.js:697:26
>       at exports.inFiber (/home/test/.meteor/tools/d699ad29da/tools/fiber-helpers.js:24:12)
>
> Please fix the problem and restart.

I already have a packages file but no packages folder

Comment: Try just running `meteor -p 3001`

Comment: It doesn't give you any errors alongside that? what about if you run the older meteor in release mode `meteor --release 0.6.4.1`

Comment: Nope, only restart message, updated the question for the second question.

Comment: Try to create a new project with meteor create using 0.6.5, then remove *.css *.html *.js and copy over all of your project files. It will properly add the new "standard-app-packages" meta-package. If you  have any custom packages under /packages, you now need to meteor add them explicitly. Don't use mrt with 0.6.5 for now, it's broken.

Answer (score 3):

try to remove `.meteorite` in your home folder `(rm -rf ~/.meteorite)`
then run `mrt` (not meteor)

seems mrt recalculates npm depedency that meteor doesn't

Answer (score 3):

- This happen to me, also going back to 0.6.4.1 provided problems. Took me a while to get it running. This is what I did in a nut shell...

To find the Meteor process you can do:

```
$ ps ax | grep node | grep meteor
```

Then kill that pid

```
$ kill -9 <pid>
```

Remove meteorite hidden folder in your home folder

```
$ rm -rf ~/.meteorite
```

run meteorite again

```
mrt
```

Also check that you are in meteorite > 0.6.11
if not update meteorite like so:

```
$ sudo npm update -g meteorite
```

Last thing make sure you have standard-app-packages installed

- Seems like this happens when, installing packages :/

Comment: Thank you. I was having the same problem. This helped me. Wonder what caused the problem. Might have been change in the node version that I made to create the production app.